# Javascript pushing into array issue with parsing data from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on a project what requires me to use the US Census Bureau API. I have most of my code working on my portion of the project however, I am having a small issue that I do not understand. What I am trying to do is take a 113 objects, parse one property from each of those objects, and then place that property, all 113, into an array. Like I said, I almost have my code working. Below is what does work:

```
   for (var i = 0; i <= response.features.length; i++){
      var dataPoint = response.features[i].properties.B19013_001E;
      console.log(dataPoint);
   }
```

The above code will print out all 113 points that I need to the console. (For those that are curious, the B19013_001E is median household income and that is the data that I want for basically a 113 different 'areas' within a county.)
Now, the code does what I want but now when I make the array portion:

```
   var dataArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i <= response.features.length; i++){
      var dataPoint = response.features[i].properties.B19013_001E;
      dataArray.push(dataPoint);
   }

   console.log(dataArray);
```

When I console log my array, I only get this error message: 
play.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

What I don't understand is how come I can get all 113 points that I need individually to the console but I have an issue when I am putting them into the array? One thing that I thought of was that maybe one of the points is not present? But when I look at the console logging of 113 points I get nothing as null or undefined. Any help will be great and thank you!

Comment: i < response.features.length, not <=

Comment: ^ That's the answer. Imagine you have an array with just 2 elements in it. That means `length === 2` and elements exist at index `0` and index `1`. Your loop means you're also trying to access index `2` (or however long your actual array is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Array.map`:

```
var dataArray = response.features.map(function(feature) {
   return feature.properties.B19013_001E;
})
```

You are getting that error because `<=` puts the last iteration outside of the bounds of your data collection. You could just change that to `<`

Comment: should seems like a strong word

Comment: You nailed it! The most pathetic thing is that my other code, parsing this data, had the <! Very frustrating. Minor thing I over looked! Thank you for the help!

Comment: "Should" may be strong, but it seems appropriate.  Using `map` helps avoid this class of mistakes and makes it much more clear what you're trying to do.  Similarly with `filter`, `reduce`, `some`, `includes`, etc.